# I imported a blend file into unity which contained 3 animations but I can only see one

Tags: animation, unity

Here is my problem: [image: as you can see there is only one clip when there should be three!]

[image: And here there are three animations.]

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I usually animate inside unity. There you can manage the animations with the animator. Or you could try to save the animations as individual files. Some professionals save all their animations into one animations, they can separate them in unity. I hope some of these will answer your question.